# facebook.GraphAPIError: (#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: True python faceebook-sdk

Tags: python, facebook, python-2.7, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api

i get this error an every time i run my code this error are from the api lib in this line

> graph.put_object(str(object_id), 'feed',message="hola")

```
access_token=''
import facebook 
graph=facebook.GraphAPI(access_token)
groups = graph.get_connections(id='me', connection_name='groups')
data = groups['data']
for s in data:
    l = s.values()    
    object_id= l[0]
    try:
        graph.put_object(str(object_id), 'feed',message="hola")

        print('Done, Posted in %s'%l[1].encode('utf-8',errors='ignore'))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

print 'Done, Posted in all groups'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending `True` instead of group ID. That's because when you are calling `values()` on a dict, values are returned in an arbitrary order. At least in CPython. [Docs for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

Thus you can't be sure that group ID would be at `0` index in the values list. You can get group ID by `id` key (full list of all fields that are sent can be seen [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/groups#Reading) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group#read)). Change

```
l = s.values()    
object_id= l[0]
```

to

```
object_id = s['id']
```